# Why can't I move the Bones?

Tags: bones

I selected the armature, I am in pose mode and no bones are showing up. Am I doing something wrong? It would make sense if I am, as I am a beginner but I looked to see if this happened to anyone else and it never did.

[image: o]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/   enter the URL of this page and upload

Answer (score 1):

First you need to see bones. Go to **properties** pane, select the **object** (the cube icon) and find **x-Ray** and switch on that field. After that you see armature, and you can select one of the bones from the armature.

Second, go to **properties** pane, click on the **human icon** (data) and select **pose position**.   Rest position is for edit bones, pose position is for animation.